# How do I call a class function from an event listener internally?

Tags: javascript, class, events, scope

I'm trying to build up my `JavaScript` knowledge base and am having difficulty with calling a `function` within my `class` when an `event` is fired from the `class` object's `textbox`. I think this is going to be related to a scope issue, but I'm not entirely sure. Doing this in `C#` was much, much easier.

```js
class FilterableDropdown {
 constructor(containerID) {
  this.ContainerID = containerID;
  this.Container = document.getElementById(containerID);
  this.Container.innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="txt-' + containerID + '-dropdown" />'
  
  // Add sub-controls.
  this.Textbox = document.getElementById("txt-" + containerID + "-dropdown");
  
  
  // Add events to sub-controls.
  this.Textbox.addEventListener("keyup", this.Filter);
 }
 Filter() {
  alert(this.ContainerID);
 }
}

var dropdown = new FilterableDropdown("fd-test");
```

```css
.filterable-dropdown > input[type=text] {
 padding: 5px;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #3332;
  color: #eee;
}
.filterable-dropdown > input[type=text]:focus { background-color: #3338; }
*:focus { outline: none; }
```

```html
<div id="fd-test" class="filterable-dropdown"></div>
```

In order to replicate the issue, simply type any character into the `textbox` to raise the `keyup` event. This will cause an alert to display `undefined`.

---

- Why is `this.ContainerID` returning as `undefined` here?

  - I believe this is due to a scoping issue.

How do I call a `function` within my `class` on a `sub-control`'s event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `this` to the `Filter` method. The `this` should point to the class instance.

That can be achieved by using `Array.prototype.bind(thisContext)` where the `thisContext` would be your class `FilterableDropdown` instance:

```js
class FilterableDropdown {
 constructor(containerID) {
  this.ContainerID = containerID;
  this.Container = document.getElementById(containerID);
  this.Container.innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="txt-' + containerID + '-dropdown" />'
  
  // Add sub-controls.
  this.Textbox = document.getElementById("txt-" + containerID + "-dropdown");
  
  
  // Bind this to the Filter method
  this.Textbox.addEventListener("keyup", this.Filter.bind(this));
 }
 Filter() {
  alert(this.ContainerID);
 }
}

var dropdown = new FilterableDropdown("fd-test");
```

```css
.filterable-dropdown > input[type=text] {
 padding: 5px;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #3332;
  color: #eee;
}
.filterable-dropdown > input[type=text]:focus { background-color: #3338; }
*:focus { outline: none; }
```

```html
<div id="fd-test" class="filterable-dropdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you will want to do is bind the method to the class using

```
this.Textbox.addEventListener("keyup", this.Filter.bind(this));
```

```js
class FilterableDropdown {
 constructor(containerID) {
  this.ContainerID = containerID;
  this.Container = document.getElementById(containerID);
  this.Container.innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="txt-' + containerID + '-dropdown" />'
  
  // Add sub-controls.
  this.Textbox = document.getElementById("txt-" + containerID + "-dropdown");
  
  
  // Add events to sub-controls.
  this.Textbox.addEventListener("keyup", this.Filter.bind(this));
 }
 Filter() {
  alert(this.ContainerID);
 }
}

var dropdown = new FilterableDropdown("fd-test");
```

```css
.filterable-dropdown > input[type=text] {
 padding: 5px;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #3332;
  color: #eee;
}
.filterable-dropdown > input[type=text]:focus { background-color: #3338; }
*:focus { outline: none; }
```

```html
<div id="fd-test" class="filterable-dropdown"></div>
```